# How to deploy and debug war application with smart tomcat in intellij

Tags: web, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a plain text java project in intellij, the project contains some java modules, one of the module is web application module, it will be generated a war file finally. All the modules build is manven.

After the maven build, the war file will be generated under /module/target/application-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.war

Now what I have

1.Intellij community edition 2021.3.2

2.Smart tomcat 4.3.7

3.Tomcat 9.0.68

4.Maven 3.8.6

The target is

1.Add tomcat run/debug configuration which can include the War file

2.Before each launch of the war application, all modules should be built firstly
3.After the application startup, I can debug

Is this doable? if yes may I know how to configure this in intellij?